# Question "asked" field in sidebar should display actual time on hover

Tags: feature-request, information-display

It would be really nice, if on the "asked" field that's displayed in the sidebar to the right of the question, that hovering over that would show the exact time that the question was asked, so that I could see specifically when I asked a question.

I'm actually waiting on another question to go past the two day point, so that I can put a bounty on it, but showing "yesterday" doesn't really help.  It could be an hour from now, it could be 24 hours from now until it reaches this point, so showing the actual asked time would be great!

Edit: It would actually be better if it showed it in my time, instead of Z, but that's another feature request :)

Comment: i clarified the title and post to indicate that you're talking about the sidebar, since this is already done in the post sig

Comment: If you want it to show your time, I wrote a GreaseMonkey script that will do it: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12635/greasemonkey-script-to-display-absolute-timestamps-in-local-time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good idea, but you can also find out this information by hovering over the "asked 27 secs ago" field below the question (just above where it shows your gravatar).

Comment: Not on CW questions that have been edited.

Comment: @Shog9: Why would anyone put a bounty on a CW question?  That might destroy the universe.  Stop trying to destroy the universe, you universe-hating jerk.  It's the only one we've got.

Comment: @Shog9: I didn't realize that...

Comment: Stop hording universes, Pesto. For all you know, the only reason we're stuck with the one is that everyone's too obsessed with not destroying it to find another one. We could be sitting on big sparkling *piles* of them, but for your obstinate refusal to embrace destruction.

Comment: Huh.  Never knew that.  Wonder why it does it there, but not on the sidebar...

Answer (score 0):

I just did that and it does...I hovered over the "Asked 52 secs ago" on your question and it said '2009-09-10 15:30:57'

Didn't realize you were talking about on the right side. I thought you were meaning on the signature at the bottom of the question.

Comment: they're talking about in the sidebar

Comment: Noticed that as soon as I read your answer.